# fprintf does not write to file

Tags: c++, printf

does anyone see, why fprintf does not write to file while printf works fine?

```
 FILE* database;
  database = fopen("database.txt", "a+");



   for (x=-200; x<200; x=x+10)
    {     
TH1F *hist_Deg = new TH1F("h1", "title", 250, -0.5, 249.5);

 for (j=5000; j<5010; j++)

 {
      sprintf(filename,"electronsrough/105.000000MeV/x%d/y0/process%d.txt", x,j);

      FILE* pfile =fopen(filename,"r");

      while(!feof(pfile))
        {
          fscanf(pfile, "%lf /n", &p);

          hist_Deg->Fill(p);
          } 
fclose(pfile);

 }

 meana = hist_Deg->GetMean();


 f->SetPoint(i, x, meana);
 i=i+1;


 fprintf(database, "%f\n", meana);
 printf("%f\n", meana);

 delete hist_Deg;

}
```

printf outputs meana to the comman line, but

The file "database.txt" is created but remains empty.

Answer (score 3):

Flushing and closing the database file should do the job.

```
fprintf(database, "%f\n", meana);
fflush(database);
fclose(database);
```

Comment: Thank you!! Okay, if I fclose, of course I will have to fopen inside the loop. Works!

Comment: One more question: I now always write to the end of the file. How do I delete all entries when I start a programm?

Comment: @Katju Instead of opening with `fopen(..., "a+")` (which specifically says `a`ppend), open with `"w"` or `"w+"` (which means `w`rite).